# From data.frame to matrix

Tags: r, dataframe

I knew to R; I have a data fame with 8 variables (columns) and 587632 observation (rows).

```
AggregateActivities <- data.frame(sleep, eating, personalcare, cooking, houseclean, laundry, ironing, travel)
```

I would like to convert AggregateActivities the data frame into a matrix such as

```
dat <- matrix(c( values from AggregateActivities)  nrow=587632, ncol=8, byrow=TRUE)
```

Can somebody help me wit this please

Comment: `dat <- as.matrix(AggregateActivities)`? or `cbind` the vectors directly

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
AggregateActivities <- data.frame(sleep, eating, personalcare)
```

To This:

```
AggregateActivities <- matrix(data.frame(sleep, eating, personalcare))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function data.matrix is specifically built for that purpose>

```
AggMat <- data.matrix( AggregateActivities )
```